# How to render login error message in product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, session, frontend-error

If a user tries to login with wrong credentials then normally a message appears which says "login failed", it works if I do it on the normal login form at `/customer/account/login/`

But if I am at a product and attempt to login with wrong credentials then the site just reloads but no error messages shows. But if I then go to the site `/customer/account/login/` then I see that the error message is rendered there.

If I attempt to login two times with wrong credentials in the product page and then go back to `/customer/account/login/`, then the message is getting rendered two times.

I looked up the code from the login page to find out which codeline is needed to show the error messages and found this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
```

so I added it to the product view, but it is still not rendering.

I also added this code:

```
<?php
$debugObject = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages();

echo "Last added message: '" . $debugObject->getLastAddedMessage() . "' <br><br>";
echo "getErrors: " . var_dump($debugObject->getErrors()) . " <br><br>";
```

Now I get this output:

```
Last added message: ''

array(1) { [0]=> object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Error)#137 (6) { ["_type":protected]=> string(5) "error" ["_code":protected]=> string(39) "Ungültiger Benutzername oder Passwort." ["_class":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_method":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_identifier":protected]=> NULL ["_isSticky":protected]=> bool(false) } } getErrors:
```

But I still don't know how I can show the message in a regular way.

---

I was only able to hack it into the view (app\design\frontend\venedor\custom\template\catalog\product\view.phtml) like this, but I don't think that this is the way to go:

```
<?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); ?>
<?php if ($session->getMessages()->toString()) { ?>

    <div class="messages">
        <div class="alert alert-danger error-msg">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo str_replace ('error: ', '', $session->getMessages()->toString()) ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $session->getMessages()->clear(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

There must be a cleaner solution. Why is `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>` not working on the product view?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to edit **catalog.xml** and add "***core/messages***" block in product page as below :

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"?>
    // rest of code here
</reference>
```